# How to extract a text between a specific characters from left in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Use-case 1   '/XXX/YYY/ZZZZZ'
Use-case 2   '/XXX/BBB_CCCC_DDD'

In both the use-cases, I like to extract XX as output.
Means always extract text between / and - .. however – should be taken the last one from left and / should taken first one from left.
Hope the explanation is clear .. Please let me know in-case something unclear.
Appreciate quick help !!

Regards,
Raj

Comment: take a look at the `RXReplace()` function. I can provide more detail tomorrow if you haven't solved it

Answer (score 1):

```
Left(RXReplace(YOUR_STRING, ".*\/", "", ""), 4)
```

So this expression will remove anything before (and including) the last slash. Then it will take the 4 first characters. This will result in "L06B" on your above examples.

BeST Regards